# VS error message while scaffolding identity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Can someone help me understand this Visual Studio error message and suggest a fix?
I am getting the error message while scaffolding Identity.

This is the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXSM7.png) I get:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Error: An
>   assembly specified in the applciation dependencies manifest
>   (Intacct.deps.json) has already been found but with a different file
>   extension: package:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design', version: '3.1.0'
>   path: 'lib/net461/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator-design.exe' previously
>   found assembly:
>   'C:\MyPath\Users\MyUser.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design\3.1.0\lib\netcoreapp3.1\dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator-design.dll

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Amy. I ended up removing the Nuget package causing the issue. I was then able to scaffold and get Identiy pages and classes I was after.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was occurred due to the NuGet manager already has a reference for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design`. in the `C:\Users\Lenovo\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design\3.1.1\` folder in C drive. 
As well as the reference was also available in the Project package

Follow the below steps to resolve the error,

1. Goto your project and Expand Dependencies tab
2. Expand packages and search for `Microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design(3.1.1)` package
3. Right-click on the package name and Remove the package.
4. Build the project and try.

Answer (score 0):

Only reinstall package.

1. open Tools-> NuGet package Manager-> Package Manager Console
2. Update-Package -reinstall